# Dell Vostro 1320, Windows 7: Plugged in Not Charging

Tags: battery, adapter

My laptop is showing plugged in not charging. I've replaced the battery thinking that might solve the problem. No luck! Any suggestion? Tried uninstalling the Device Manager> Batteries > Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery... still the problem is there.

Comment: Probably it is not a software problem but a hardware one.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times replacement battery aren't exactly compatible with the laptop (Even though they physically fit) Companies like Dell and HP tend not to like people replacing batteries non HP or Dell approved. The battery might still be charging though, have you tried unplugging the power and trying to boot the pc up? Just because it says it's not charging doesn't mean the battery isn't getting charged.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Didn't work for my machine. I almost emptied the battery because someone suggested if the charge of the battery goes below 15% it may start charging.